# How to determine the two UIButton is not the same UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton

Ｉwant to make sure ButtonA and ButtonB are the same one.

I must to judge the "title", "backgroundColor","image for Normal or image for Selected" of two Button is Equal?

Comment: swift or objective-c?

Comment: it is quite ambiguous and is up to you and to how you'd like to define _same_ eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift:

```
if button1 !== button2 {
    // they are not the same button
}
```

Objective-C:

```
if (button1 != button2) {
    // they are not the same button
}
```